# Using LSTM to predict weekly results based on different yearly target data

Tags: keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, feature-selection

Using weekly weather data, I am trying to use python/keras to anticipate, throughout the year, what a target value will be at the end of the year. But the yearly data is based on weather, and the single labeled target data at the end of the year is wheat yield.

So I'd like to say that during week 10, the weather has been very cold for 3 weeks thus the expected yield at the end of the season will be lower than expected. I have maybe 20 weather variables split and aggregated into weekly features for each. For example, I have ave_temp_week1, ave_temp_week2, for 30 weeks, and avg_precip_week1, avg_precip_week2, etc, which results in about 1000 total features. There is also a yield_trend feature that shows the trend over the SIX years of data that I have. I have several hundred thousand observations of yield that can be aggregated by county if needed.

- One question is: Is this an LSTM time-series problem that should be split by year? (training = 2013-2018 and test = 2109) or is this an LSTM sequential problem that can be split randomly (training/test = 80/20).
- The second question is most important: what would the shape of the LSTM input look like in both instances?

(This is my first stack overflow question so apologies if I have done something inappropriate).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this problem can also be solved by creating a regular Sequential model as well. If you split your data based on weeks (say 1 to 52 in a year), create feature columns based on the week value, i.e mean, std, max, min value for week 1,52. Then you can split by any random value and make sure these new features go as input to your NN model.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I'm still confused on how I can get an idea at say, week 10, of whether the yield is on track to be good at the end of the season based on the weather data to that point? My goal, and sorry if I wasn't clear, is not to predict end of season yield, but to get an idea earlier in the year as to whether it's on track, so that expectations can be managed. I'm sure I'm missing obvious information here. Any thoughts?